# Converting SWF to WMV

Tags: video, conversion, video-conversion, swf

I've been searching on the web for tools (online and desktop) to convert SWF files to WMV. We don't have the original FLA files anymore, and these SWF contain how-to software instructions.

Some tools I've tried: MediaCoder, Format Factory, SWF Decompiler (kept freezing up), and File Wiggler (online tool). They either crashed or couldn't handle SWF-to-WMV conversion. Anyone know of a good, free tool for this task on Windows 7? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to convert them to WMV? Maybe another file format would work better with the software you tried.

Otherwise, it seems as if you've gone through a lot of software already; I'm not sure if any other software would really do the trick.

Instead, you could try screen-recording the SWF files while they are playing. Try recording the SWF file while it is playing with [Screenr](http://www.screenr.com/) and download the video that is created. Make sure you're not playing any other music/sound effects while recording it.

Another option you could try is using Google's new lab, [Swiffy](http://swiffy.googlelabs.com/). It can convert SWF files to HTML5. I don't know how well it works, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, skoshy. I need to convert them to a format that will work with SharePoint 2010's built-in media player. WMV is supported by that.

Answer (score 1):

If the SWF contains video, FFMPEG can do this, as can [DeskShare](http://www.deskshare.com)'s Digital Media Converter Pro. (Discolosure: I am a former DeskShare employee, but have no current financial relationship with them.)

If the SWF contains Flash animation, you'll need to use screen recording software as @skoshy suggested.

Comment: Thanks, CarlF. Is DeskShare free or paid software?

Comment: DeskShare is a for-money software company--what used to be called "Shareware".

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with Xilisoft.  The trial version converted .swf to .wmv, but only if it was 3 minutes or less in length.